How can I allow my app to run on Android 10 while targeting API 33
I received a message in the Play store developer console that my app was in violation of the Google Play Developer Programme Policies. The reason given was "App must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher". I re-built the app targeting that API level and submitted an update, which was approved overnight. Now I'm hearing from Android 10 users who want to buy my app that they can't because it isn't compatible with their device. They are continuing to receive updates on these devices for other software. I feel I must be misunderstanding something and that by targeting API level 33 I have cut out a big part of my potential user base. Is there something I've done wrong here? I'm wondering if there is a way to target API 33 while maintaining compatibility with previous versions of Android.

there is difference between target sdk and min sdk.
min sdk is the minimum API level that your app requires to run(like if it is set to the sdk correspondent to android 8 your app can't run on android 7 or below).
while target sdk is the API level that your app is designed to run on and google play requires it to be 33(android 13) or higher.
you can change them from build.gradle (:app) app level also make sure that the app source code is designed to work on the versions you specified

Thank you for clarifying this. I checked my app build.gradle and minSdk is 32, while targetSdk is 33. It sounds like I need to change minSdk to 29 to allow it to run on Android 10. Would you recommend going lower than 29 to maximise the devices it can run on?

of course actually the recommended minimum sdk is 26(android 8).

Wonderful, thank you so much. I'm relatively new to Android development so this is very very helpful. Thank you!
